How does the Sega Master System handle a sprite moving off the left edge of the screen?
The NES and SMS have horizontal resolution 256. This feels like a very natural choice for that tech level; apart from giving roughly square pixels on a CRT, it allows pixel position for e.g. sprites to be represented in an 8-bit integer.
But there is a problem when an object represented by a sprite, must move off the left edge of the screen. To do this smoothly, requires representing states where part of the sprite has moved off the left edge of the screen, which means the sprite position (which is measured from the first sprite pixel) must be a negative number. But all the possible values of an 8-bit register, 0 to 255, are already used to represent states where the sprite is fully visible, or partly moved off the right edge of the screen.
How does the NES handle this? It doesn't. Games must either implement some brute force solution using e.g. extra sprite bitmaps, or just accept that an object reaching the left edge of the screen will abruptly disappear. Super Mario Brothers does the latter. (On an NTSC TV, the NES overscans somewhat, so this is less noticeable on the CRT hardware for which the system was designed.)
What about the Sega Master System?
Does the SMS have special provision for a sprite moving off the left edge of the screen, and if so, how exactly does it work?

It might be best to remove the part what ChatGPT generated for you. It is wrong and not relevant to the question what ChatGPT might say about it.

@Justme Mmm, looked to me like it was basically correct based on your answer, but okay, done.

There is a bit called Overflow but it is indeed a status flag indicating you had more than 8 sprites per one scanline (even off-screen ones). There is no bit to indicate negative position or to extend the range, just a bit to start sprite handling 8 pixels earlier than default.

Both the NES and SMS handle it in the same way. There is a bit (6th bit of register $00 on the SMS VDP, 2nd and 3rd bit in $2001 on the NES) which controls whether the left most 8 pixels of the screen are drawn. On the NES it's possible to distinguish between drawing sprites and drawing the background.
Using these control bits will change the resolution from 256 horizontally to 248 and makes it so the visible screen starts at x=8. This provides the space to allow sprites to disappear off the left side of the screen. You can see this in the image below.

The reason you might notice a difference is that on the NES reducing the resolution (and adding a noticable blank area on the left side of the screen) is not explicitly required so many games didn't do it. But on the SMS it is a requirement for any horizontal scrolling since the SMS tilemap is not only limited to 32 tiles across, it also does not render partial tiles correctly on the left side of the screen the way the NES can.

There is one provision.
When VDP register $00 bit 3 is set, all sprites are shifted left by 8 pixels.
This allows to shift sprites in or out on the left side.
But then it does not allow shifting any sprite in or out on the right side of screen.
At least unless you deliberately make the screen 8 pixels narrower on the right side by putting high priority background tiles in the rightmost columnt.

Ah, that is interesting! On the face of it, there would seem to be room for big improvement at little cost by providing 8 such bits, one per sprite. I wonder is there some reason that would have cost more than I would have expected?

@rwallace It likely would have been complex to add per sprite, as all the bit does is to select at what coordinate the sprite engine start handling all of them with equal X coordinate. You would need a 9-bit pixel counter and 9-bit X coordinates, and the Sprite Attribute Table is already 3 full bytes per sprite. The VDP is a modifed/expanded  TI TMS9918, and they seemed to have made bugs while expanding it to show 8 sprites per scanline instead of four. There's 8 sprite slots in hardware (like FIFO) and the VDP can process 64 sprites from the sprite table, as long as there's max 8 per line.
